# Getting HREF Values from content on page

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting data from a page that is formatted like this

```
<span id="RANDOMINFO">
 <a href="/DEMO/RANDOMDATA">+</a>
 <span title="1">DATA I WANT HERE</span> 
<a href="https://URL.COM/">CLICK</a> 
<a href="https://URL.COM/">MORE RANDOM DATA</a>
</span>
<span id="RANDOMINFO">
 <a href="/DEMO/RANDOMDATA">+</a>
 <span title="2">DATA I WANT HERE</span> 
<a href="https://URL.COM/RANDOM">CLICK</a> 
<a href="https://URL.COM/RANDOM">MORE RANDOM DATA</a>
</span>
```

How can I get the href value from the page

Here is the code I have to get the data from the `span ID` but don't know how to do it for the `href` as there is `no name or id`

```
       $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html2);
                foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $element ) 
                    { 
                        if (!empty($element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value)) 
                        { 
                        $filename = 'newpks/'.$f.'.txt';
                         $file = fopen($filename,"a");

                        $data = $element->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value.PHP_EOL;
                        fwrite($file,$data);
                        fclose($file);
                        $i++;
                        $end = $start;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: In html you shown span hasn't any href attribute. Please show which tag you want to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're only interested in links with the `href` attribute, and then we know the tags will be of type `a`. This should sufficient (I haven't been able to test the code though).

I optimized the code a bit, since the [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) class inherits from [`DOMElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) you can use the [`hasAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.hasattribute.php) and [`getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) instead.

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $element ) { 
    if ($element->hasAttribute('href')) { 
        $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
        // Do your work here
    }
}
```

Comment: *I have to get the data from the span ID*

Comment: Many Thanks
Im already getting the data from the span so can just add this after the first foreach loop

will accept answer soon as it lets me

Comment: Cheers @ChrisYates, I just updated the answer after your comment, it should be a bit optimized for your purpose. If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll reverse my changes.

Comment: actually this will still help as both a tags have href attributes with values and you must have read my mind because now I can get the data from the extra tag as well :thumbsup: